# Responsive popup once per day

Tags: javascript, css, session, popup, local-storage

This code is to display a pop up  once per day. But I'm having trouble making it responsive, and it seems that it shows once a lifetime...

I put it in 3 different pages, and if it displays on one of them, it doesn't display in the other pages.

```js
let localStorage = {};

if (localStorage.last) {
    if ((localStorage.last - Date.now() ) / (1000*60*60*24) >= 1) {

    // Date.now() is in milliseconds, so convert it all to days, and if
    // it's more than 1 day, show the div

        $(document).ready(function() { 
            var id = '#dialog';
            var maskHeight = $(document).height();
            var maskWidth = $(window).width();
 
            $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight}); 
            $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();
            $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
            $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
            $(id).fadeIn(2000);
 
            $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#mask').hide();
                $('.window').hide();
            });
 
            $('#mask').click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('.window').hide();
            });
        });
        localStorage.last = Date.now(); //Reset your timer
    }
} else {
    localStorage.last = Date.now();
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var id = '#dialog';
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight}); 
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);
 
        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#mask').hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });
 
        $('#mask').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.window').hide();
        });
    });
}
```

```css
#mask {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:9000;
    background-color:#26262c;
    display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:440px;
    height:850px;
    display:none;
    z-index:9999;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#boxes #dialog {
    width:450px; 
    height:auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
.agree:hover{
    background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.popupoption:hover{
    background-color:#D1D1D1;
    color: green;
}
.popupoption2:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
    <div style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
        <div id="san">
            <a href="#" class="close agree">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-close-512.png" width="25" style="float:right; margin-right: -10px; margin-top: -10px;" alt="" />
            </a> 
            <br><br>
            Visit our new website: <a style="color:blue" target="_blank" href="www.example.come">Example.com</a>. 
            <br><br><br>&#160;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 2478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 1202px; display: none; opacity: 0.4;" id="mask">&#160;</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I tried replacing my JS by this one, but still didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
             console.log("do nothing");
            } else {

                $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

                var id = '#dialog';
              var maskHeight = $(document).height();
              var maskWidth = $(window).width();
              $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight}); 
              $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
              $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
                    var winH = $(window).height();
              var winW = $(window).width();
                    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
              $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
                 $(id).fadeIn(2000);  
                 $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#mask').hide();
              $('.window').hide();
                 });  
                 $('#mask').click(function () {
                      $(this).hide();
                      $('.window').hide();
                     });  
            }
 });
```

Comment: can we see the html code?

Comment: yes it has been edited, it's over there

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set a browser [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Somewhere in the execution of your popup, you create the cookie with an expiry date of 24 hours from when it has been set.

Setting the cookie with expiry:

```
const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate( tomorrow.getDate() + 1 )
document.cookie = `popupShown=true; expires=${ tomorrow }`;
```

You will need to add some logic around checking the cookie status before displaying the popup.

As for being responsive you may want to swap out fixed-widths for percentages, or at least use responsive breakpoints with media queries.

Comment: how? what's popupShown=true?

Comment: const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate( tomorrow.getDate() + 1 );
Cookies.set = "popupShown',true, expires=${ tomorrow }";
console.log(Cookies.get('popupShown'));
$(function() {
  if (Cookies.get('popupShown'))
 {
     Cookies.set('popupShown', true, {expires: 1});
      showpopup();
  }
});

Comment: @MerGh `popupShown` is the value stored in the cookie. If you set it when you call the popup, you won't have to check for the false case. Just check to see if the cookie exists before you activate the popup. Read the link in the post about browser cookies, it's got the specifics I think you're after :)